# concrete parameter type vs wildcard signature

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use a wildcard type in a method signature and pass different parameterized types. If I parameterize a Map with my item, Eclipse starts complaining:

```
The method DoStuff(Map<String,Test.GenericItemWrapper<?>>) in the type Test 
is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,Test.GenericItemWrapper<String>>)
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Test
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<Long>> longWrapper = null;
    Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<String>> stringWrapper = null;

    Test t = new Test();
    t.DoStuff(longWrapper); // error here
    t.DoStuff(stringWrapper); // error here
  }

  public void DoStuff(Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<?>> aParam)
  {

  }

  public static class GenericItemWrapper<ItemType>
  {
    private ItemType mItem;

    public GenericItemWrapper()
    {
      this(null);
    }

    public GenericItemWrapper(ItemType aItem)
    {
      mItem = aItem;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is in construction `new GenericItemWrapper<Long>();` - it requires a parameter, but there is none.

Comment: @amorfis You modified the code in the OP's question. Please, [revert it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2032415).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski I only modified the formatting, but I can't find a way to see modification history or revert it.

Comment: @amorfis Ah, I see. The code between "<" and ">" must have been treated as an HTML tag, and it was not printed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51669738/revisions) it looked like you added the type parameters. Sorry for my accusation, then, and thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski Ok, I see the problem now :) Thanks. Is there some link to "revisions"? Or you need to type the URL by hand?

Comment: The code as shown has no reason to trigger the error message described. Please show a complete example we can copy/paste and run as-is without any modification, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @amorfis You need to click on the "edited XXX ago" link at the bottom of the post :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and clarify if you have corrected the problem (with the constructor parameter) or if you simply forgot it ... the [edit v3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51669738/3) invalidate [Murat K. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51669865/4391450) ...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parameter for instantiating `GenericItemWrapper`. Should be

```
GenericItemWrapper<Long> longWrapper = new GenericItemWrapper<Long>(1l); // example number
```

but you don't need that constructor as far as I can see since you can always access the generic type `ItemType` within the class.

Comment: Everyone !! Be aware that this solution was provide before this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51669738/3).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Map<String,Test.GenericItemWrapper<String>>` is not instance of `Map<String,Test.GenericItemWrapper<?>>`, even if `String` is kind of "instance of" `?`.

Just like `List<String>` is not assignable to a variable of type `List<Object>`. In Java there is no type covariance ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science) )